# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, cursor

// This is not working. It shows first record and stops after that. I want a loop that keep running even after the last record. I got your point that cursor starts form position 0.
    //Code

```
cur=db.getData(position);

    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.next :
    { 

        if (cur != null && cur.getCount()> 0 && position < cur.getCount() && position != cur.getCount()){
            cur.moveToPosition(position);
            textView1.setText(""+cur.getString(1));// Display Columns 
            position++;
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

// I want a loop to display record number

for next button
eg:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

back button
eg:

```
5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1
```

random button
eg:

```
3 4 5 1
5 1 2 3
4 5 1 2
```

Comment: I want to fetch record one by one using position of cursor. I don't want to use.

Comment: this exception appears just first time? remember index starts at 0

Answer (score 5):

That exception appears, because you are trying to get the object in a position that do not exist. Remember index start at 0.

Direct from DOCS :

```
 public abstract boolean moveToPosition (int position)
```

Added in API level 1

Move the cursor to an absolute position. The valid range of values is -1 <= position <= count.

This method will return true if the request destination was reachable, otherwise, it returns false.
Parameters
position    the zero-based position to move to.
Returns

```
whether the requested move fully succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cur != null && cur.getCount()> 0 && position < cur.getCount() && position != cur.getCount()){
                        cur.moveToPosition(position);
                        textView1.setText(""+cur.getString(1));// Display Columns 
                    }
```

Comment: Also make sure That you cursor have more then or equal to 1 columns in it. If you want to access 1st column then cur.getString(0). In Cursor, Indexing start from 0. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Call get data before increments position, that because you are trying to acceed an element in a unexisting I'm your db.

```
cur =db. getData(position) ;
```

Then

```
position++;
```

Remember to first of all declare position = 0